# Running .model programs with open AI gym?

Tags: openai-gym

I was given access to a bunch of trained agents that are able to play some atari games pretty well. The extension of these agents is .model, and I was told I am able to run them using openAI gym somehow? I've been looking around the documentation of open AI but there does not seem to be anything useful. Does anyone have any idea how to go about doing this (watching the models play)?